# Powershell Regex Function Deleting CRLFs

Tags: regex, powershell

I am using the below function to create a JSON file from a SQL file. Unfortunately it is deleting the CRLF at the end of each line of the SQL file. I want it to keep them instead.

```
 function GetStringBetweenTwoStrings($firstString, $secondString, $importPath){
>>
>>     #Get content from file
>>     $file = Get-Content $importPath
>>
>>     #Regex pattern to compare two strings
>>     $pattern = "$firstString(.*?)$secondString"
>>
>>     #Perform the opperation
>>     $result = [regex]::Match($file,$pattern).Groups[1].Value
>>    
>>     #Return result
>>     return "{""sql"":"""+$result+"""}"
>>
>> }
```

I have tried using -raw but it does not seem to work

Thanks,

John

Answer (score 0):

### Interesting question

Unfortunately, I couldn't figure out a way to keep CRLF characters from  `[regex]::Match`  command.

It captures them fine but seems to return them as a single string by default.

<strike>If someone can figure that out, I'd be glad to see it.</strike>
Thanks to people much smarter than me, the following way with `[regex]::match` seems to work

```
function Get-StringBetweenTwoStrings {
    [cmdletBinding()]
    param (
   $firstString,
   $secondString,
   $fullString
) 
    # Get content from file WITH -RAW
    $file = Get-Content -Path $fullString -Raw
    Write-Verbose $file -Verbose

    # Regex pattern to compare two strings
    $pattern = '{0}(.*?){1}' -f $firstString, $secondString
    Write-Verbose $pattern -Verbose

    # Perform the operation
    $result = [regex]::Match($file, $pattern, 'SingleLine, MultiLine, IgnoreCase').Value

    # Result
    "{""sql"":""$result""}"
}
```

#### Test the code

```
Get-StringBetweenTwoStrings -firstString '(?<=GO)' -secondString '(?=GO)' -fullString .\Downloads\test.txt
```

#### Image

[image]

### Workaround

When all else fails, I go back to brute force.

Start capturing when we see our `$firstString`, and keep capturing until we find our `$secondString` or reach the end.

#### Sample Data

```
$s = @'
# This is a random comment
GOSELECT TOP (1)
    *
FROM dbo.Users
WHERE CaffeineLevel = 'Low';
# Can we get a cafGOfeine drip?
GO
# Why isn't this easier
'@  -split '\r?\n'
```

#### Code

```
$capture = [Text.StringBuilder]::new()
$capturing = $false

$firstString = 'GO'
$secondString = 'GO'

foreach ($line in $s) {
    if ($line -match $secondString -and $capturing) {
        Write-Verbose "Stopping...$line" -Verbose

        <#
            In case we want to capture a partial line
            look for everything UNTIL our second string
        #>
        $splitLine = ($line | Select-String -Pattern ".*(?=$secondString)").Matches.Value
        Write-Verbose "Capturing: [$splitLine]" -Verbose
        $null = $capture.AppendLine($splitLine)

        $capturing = $false
        <# second string found, stop altogether #>
        break
    }
    
    if ($capturing) {
        Write-Verbose "Capturing: [$line]" -Verbose
        $null = $capture.AppendLine($line)
    }

    if ($line -match $firstString) {
        Write-Verbose "Starting...$line" -Verbose

        <#
            In case we want to capture a partial line,
            look for everything AFTER our first string
        #>
        $splitLine = ($line | Select-String -Pattern "(?<=$firstString).*").Matches.Value
        Write-Verbose "Capturing: [$splitLine]" -Verbose
        $null = $capture.AppendLine($splitLine)

        $capturing = $true
    }
}

$capture.ToString()
```

#### Dirty Testing Results

[image]

Comment: Thanks I ended up not using Regex as well;function GetStringBetweenTwoStrings($firstString, $secondString, $importPath){
 $file = Get-Content $importPath
 $Nl = "`r`n"
 $start = 0
     foreach($line in $file) {
         if($start -eq 1){
             if($line -ne $secondString){
                 $result = $result + $line + $Nl
             }
             if($line -eq $secondString){
                 $start = 0
             }
         }
         if($line -eq $firstString){
             $start=1
         }
     }
     return "{""sql"":"""+$result+"""}"
 }